# Convert a python List of List to spark RDD

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am running a spark job which run in the following steps:

1. First it reads a directory of files:

   data = sc.binaryFiles()
2. Process each file separately:

   res = data.map(lambda (x,y): func_1(x,y))
3. The **func_1** call another function **func_2** which process the content of each file separately and return a list of list to **func_1**. Now I need to change this list of list to spark rdd and write the same to hdfs. But I don't have any idea how to do this.

I am very new to spark. Any help in this case will be appreciate. Thank you in advance.

**Edited:** As per suggestion, here is the Func1 and Func2 definition:

```
def Func_1(filename, file_content):
       Outputfile  = "some code for generating output file name for each input file"

       decode_data = Func_2(StringIO(file_content))

       ##save decode_data here in HDFS.

def Func2_():
    ##It does the decoding of the file in a sequence manner (its necessary as each binary file has some headers attach to each portion of the file) and return a list of list where each inner list equivalent to a row of the decoded data and out list is the collection of such rows(skipping the code as it is trivial)
```

Comment: You cannot. Nested ops like this are not supported in Spark.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you please suggest if some change in the steps of the above job can do this task?

Comment: Why do you want to save individual elements?

Comment: Actually we have around 1 million of binary files (size 20 MB to 300 MB) and we are trying to decode each file (as a byte array) separately. Each byte array must be decoded in a sequential manner (its necessary). So i am passing each file using map to my function func_1 that decode the file and generate a millions of record from each file. I am appending those records in a list (so I have a list of list) and finally I want to save this list of list  (so i am generating such list of list for each of the binary file) to HDFS. I am running this job using yarn-client on a powerful hadoop cluster

Comment: Well, there are HDFS clients accessible in Python which, in theory, could be used here.

Comment: You need to provide code of `func_1` and `func_2`. I think you may just need `flatMap` --- the result is already a RDD. Since you're running on a hadoop cluster, chances are you could directly write to HDFS from spark, e.g., `res.saveAsTextFile('hdfs:///path/to/result/')`